# SASS: adding extend in mixin

Tags: css, sass

I have three sass files (with all necessary imports):

- header
- variables
- sprites

in variables i have:

```
@mixin svg-sprite($sprite) {
  @extend .{$sprite};
  @extend .{$sprite}-res;
}
```

in header i'm calling:

```
@include svg-sprite(".logo");
```

and in sprites:

```
%svg-common {
    background: url("svg/sprite.view.svg") no-repeat;
}

.logo {
    @extend %svg-common;
    background-position: 0 58.3969465648855%;
}

.logo-res {
    width: 180px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

but i got errors:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "  @extend": expected selector, was ".{$sprite};"
        on line ** of ****.scss
>>   @extend .{$sprite};
```

what i do wrong?

Comment: @Harry maybe there is any workaround?
to use my sprite?

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment. I stand corrected. The answer given below works for me and seems like Sass does support it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot the `#` when interpolating within the `mixin`

The lines of code should look like this

```
@mixin svg-sprite($sprite) {
  @extend #{$sprite};
  @extend #{$sprite}-res;
}
```

Comment: You're correct. So Sass does allow `@extend` with interpolated selector. I stand corrected.

Comment: Yeah it does. Interpolation is very powerful and works fine when dealing with selectors.

Comment: I keep getting this error when trying to do this:  Extend directives may only be used within rules.